# How to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2-2\cos t}$

Tags: integration, arc-length

I having some problems with the integration of $\sqrt{2-2\cos t}$. I got it by calculating the length of the arc

\begin{align}
\gamma (t) &= (t - \sin t,1 - \cos t), \quad t\in[0,2\pi] \\
\implies \dot{\gamma(t)} &= (1 - \cos t, \sin t) \\
\implies \vert\vert\dot{\gamma(t)}\vert\vert &= \sqrt{(1 - \cos t)^2+(\sin t)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{2-2\cos t} 
\end{align}

How can I do?

Comment: Hint: 1-cos(x)=2sin^2(x/2)

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos t)}=\sin \frac{t}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have,

$\sqrt2 \sqrt{1 - \cos t }$

= $\sqrt2 \sqrt{2 \sin^2 \frac{t}{2}}$

= $ 2 \sin \frac{t}{2}$

Now integrate it.

= 2 $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin \frac{t}{2}$

Comment: May be with an absolute value ;o)

Comment: @Bernard can you please explain the meaning of your comment.

Comment: @Semiclassical Can you please explain taking my answer as refrence because most of the time I do questions like this. And always get correct result.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is fine. The issue I was concerned with was whether $\sqrt{\sin^2(t/2)}=\sin(t/2)$ was valid; it isn't true for $t\in(2\pi,4\pi),$ for instance. _But_ this objection is actually spurious: the equality is valid on the domain of integration. So there's no problem.

Comment: @Semiclassical then why someone downvoted my answer.

Comment: Yes, is corret, But why $1-cost$=$2sin^2\frac{t}{2}$

Comment: This is a formula  $1 - cos n\theta = 2 sin^2 \frac{n\theta}{2}$. Also $1 + cos n\theta = 2 cos^2 \frac{n\theta}{2}$

Comment: If -ve sign before cos its change into sin and angle becomes half.

Comment: If still any doubt please ask.

Comment: I meant the same  (general) objection as Semiclassical: there should be some words to justify why no absolute value. Let me add I didn't down vote – it was just a comment. Unfortunately there's  a number of temperamental persons on this site :-(

Comment: @Bernard ok. But semiclassical says its fine. Is it not?

Comment: For *me*,  it's   fine. Actually, it depends on whom it is addressed to: for  some people, it goes without saying, for other people, it might let them think that in all cases $\sqrt{A^2}=A$. That's what I wanted to point out.